# Widget not listed in ICS

Tags: android, widget, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am implementing a widget for my app for the first time, so I took it easy -- used online examples and created a working, very simple widget fine. It works fine in the emulator and on my Honeycomb tablet, but when I try to add it to my home page on my Nexus S with Ice Cream Sandwich, the Widget isn't listed among all the other widgets. Am I doing something wrong? For the juice, here's the simple pieces parts of my widget. As I said, I'm just trying to figure this out and expand from there, once I get the basic framework.

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyDJAppWidgetProvider" android:label="@string/widget_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/mdj_doublewide" />
</receiver>
```

Widget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  android:minWidth="146dip"
  android:minHeight="72dip"
  android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_message"
  android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"  
</appwidget-provider>
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center"
android:layout_margin="4dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/widget_word"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem. It was simply a syntax error in the xml definition of the widget itself. I had the > after the xmlns:android line rather than at the end of the statement (android:updatePeriodMillis). My new definition looks like this, and after a reboot (as pointed out as needed in 4.0 elsewhere), the widget now shows up -- and is a double-wide widget as it should be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:minHeight="72dp"
  android:minWidth="146dp"
  android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_message"
  android:updatePeriodMillis="720000" > 
</appwidget-provider>
```

Oh Happy Day. Now to make this widget say something besides the time :)